# In C++, can I use the arrow operator to access another operator?

Tags: c++, operators

I have a pointer to some functor.

```
class Functor {
public:
    double operator()(int arg) {
        return 0;
    }
};

Functor* functorInstance = new Functor();
```

Do I have to call it like this?

```
double result = (*functorInstance)(arg);
```

Or is there some way to use `->` in this case?

Comment: No, this is the only way to invoke through a function pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a FUNCTOR, not a function as you said before, you can call it using the -> syntax what you need to do is functor->operator()(args).

If you want to convert the function to a functor you could write the template like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename ret_t, typename... args_t>
class myfunctor{

  private:
    ret_t (*funct)(args_t...);

  public:
    myfunctor (ret_t (*function)(args_t...)){
      funct = function;
    }

    ret_t operator()(args_t... args){ return (*funct)(args...);}
};


int test(int a){
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
  return a;
}


int main(){
  myfunctor<int, int> t(&test);
  t(3);  
  myfunctor<int, int> * t2 = new myfunctor<int, int>(&test);
  t2->operator()(3);
  (*t2)(3);

}
```